# transfering wordpress site form one localhost to another localhost

Tags: php, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm trying to move wp site from localhost on my work computer to my personal computer. I have followed these steps:

1. Copy wp-content folder
2. Export database
3. Import database
4. Paste wp-content folder
5. Configure config.php

It had copied all the themes and plugins, but content (images, text, pages etc) doesn't display. Did I skipped something?

Comment: 1. Check if the Database settings are correctly configured. 2. Check if the themefolder contains a theme 3. Check if you messed up the import/export, so look into phpMyAdmin if the tables are filled and correctly named.

Comment: What about your directory name?? If it's different then it won't work.

Comment: The directory name is the same

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't transfer the wp-content folder as a whole, wordpress won't like it and wont find any of the posts/images within it.

If you transfer over just the theme and plugins first so all the files are in place and then do the import of the database you may have more luck.

The only problem will be the images, which may go missing due to the fact that they cannot be downloaded via localhost. Sadly the only way i can think of fixing that is through going through each page and re-adding them.

Comment: No, it is possible to move wordpress page as a whole without re-adding anything. Check the wordpress codex page.

Comment: We don't know that. Directory name could be different.

Comment: Rhys I've tried to update wp-content folder first and than import database and I got this error:  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites/coreact/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/lang-data.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

If the URL was changed:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

I would recommend to check wp_config table in the database for the following entries:

option_name=’siteurl‘ or option_name=’home‘

and check if the values are correct for the new installation.

Comment: If the directory name is different than in original installation then these checks make sense.

Comment: the directory name and path is the same